# Bitcoin RPC - settxfee specific amount rather than based off transaction size?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

How am I able to use the "sendfrom" command with a specific amount of 0.0005 BTC as fees no matter how small or big the transaction is in bytes?

settxfee is based off fees per bytes.